# The question with only tag "Powershell" should be consider as SharePoint related question?

Tags: discussion, support

I came across [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219289/export-csv-in-an-excel-table-powershell) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219293/create-a-column-in-an-excel-table-csv-with-powershell) question today. and I found that here the requirement belong to PowerShell and Excel/CSV. There is nothing related to SharePoint here.

So, I am wondering that the question with only tag `Powershell` are part of [SP.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)? Or we should flag them *off the topic*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main and clear factor to can easily specify if this question is *off-topic* or not is The **Question Body**.

As for the questions that you referred to in your question, I totally agree with you, and your flag has been accepted and the two questions closed as *off-topic*.

Thank you so much for your valuable contributions  :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :-)